# Jquery Datatables plugin. How to read the HTML Column Heading value

Tags: datatables

I am using the JQuery Datatables plugin (https://datatables.net/).

I would like to be able to reference the original HTML `<th></th>` column header values.

```
<table border="0">
    <thead>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>data for column 1</td>
            <td>data for column 2</td>
            <td>data for column 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I know that columns can be named within the plugin using the `columns` property:

```
$('#mytable').DataTable(
    {
        columns: [
            {name: 'column1'},
            {name: 'column2'},
            {name: 'column3'}
        ]
    }
)
```

However it would be very useful when dealing with dynamically created HTML to be able to reference the HTML `<th>` tag in order to find the Datatables index for the column with a specific name.

I have had a look at `dataTable.context[0].aoHeader` and can see both and `idx` and `innerHTML` objets within that, however it looks like `table().header()` might provide a solution.

Comment: It depends how you want to use this info, and in what context. But one way is to use the DataTables [`table().header()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/table().header()) API function. Another way is to use jQuery - for example: [List all table headers in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31759741/12567365). If these don't help, you can [edit] your question to clarify - and show us what you tried already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `column.name` values shown in the question to select the DataTables column index values.

Example:

```
table.column( 'column2:name' ).index()
```

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#mytable').DataTable(
    {
      columns: [
        { name: 'column1' },
        { name: 'column2' },
        { name: 'column3' }
      ]
    }
  )

  let idx = table.column( 'column2:name' ).index();

  console.log( idx ); // prints 1 (2nd column's index)

} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="mytable" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data for column 1</td>
                <td>data for column 2</td>
                <td>data for column 3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This uses the [column()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column()) API function, together with a [column selector](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector).

There are various different ways you can provide a column selector - one of which is the way I show in the above code:

```
'YOUR_COL_NAME_HERE:name'
```

Then the `index()` function returns the zero-based column index.

---

If you have draggable columns (i.e. columns can be reordered) then you may also need to add a [selector modifier](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) to account for that, depending on what specific index you want - the original one, or the currently displayed one.

Comment: This is a great answer, however the question stated that:

"However it would be very useful when dealing with dynamically created HTML to be able to reference the HTML <th> tag in order to find the Datatables index for the column with a specific name."

The solution above used the ```Columns``` functionality, which is not what the question was asking.

Comment: Understood. My mistake. I thought by "name" you meant the `name` options shown in the question (which could be populated dynamically, and not hard-coded). But maybe the suggestions in my first comment in the question would be more helpful, in that case.